# Change/transfer bus or buses

Tags: grammar

You need to change bus(es) three times to get to a certain place.

1. You've got to transfer buses three times.
2. You've got to transfer bus three times.

Is #2 correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would presume transfers are to different buses, so 1 is the better of the two examples.

But a better word would be *change*, since *transfer* is actually the action in between the buses. So I would write:

> You've got to **change** buses three times.

or

> You've got to transfer **between** buses two times.

(assuming there are three buses total involved)

Answer (score 1):

No, number 2 is not correct. The word "between" is understood before the word "buses" in the first example. The act of transferring must involve more than one alternative, so the singular "bus" is incorrect. Neither of your examples reflect natural English speech, though. A native English speaker would say just "You've got to transfer three times."